# How to call a function in an if statement in JS

Tags: javascript

I want to do something like this: 
Say I already have a function named function()

```
If (function() == 2) {
    console.log("you are great")
}
```

How do I do this the correct way?

Comment: is your function named function?

Comment: Name the function and call it `if(nameOfYourFunction() === 2)`.

Comment: `function` is a reserved keyword in js for creating a function, don't use it as your function name

Comment: Suppose you have `function getCount() { return 2 }`. then you can do `if(getCount()==2){console.log('you are great')}`.

Answer (score 3):

You can't have function named function in JavaScript - it is reserved word. Fix to your problem would be give function a specific name when declaring it.

```
function test() {
  // just example
  return 2;
}
```

Then you can use it in if condition:

```
if (test() === 2) {
  // do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in comments you have to name your function correctly (function is a reserved word in JS) and then check your condition in if statement. Here you can find simple example:

```js
function getA() {
  return 'a';
}

if(getA() === 'a'){
  console.log('Success');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make global variable, call it with the function and return the value and call it inside the if condition.